# Get full custom log from website in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Asp.Net MVC application.

I need to get a full custom log of my website but I don't want to use Google Analytics, IIS log file and etc.

I am familiar with `CustomActionFilter` and `HttpModule`. Shall I use these or there is a better way?

Comment: You need log of user activity? Or log of application work? It's 2 different logs.

Comment: I need log of user activity. I need to get log of requests to my application for website statistic. (Total Page Views, Total Visitors and etc )

Comment: google analytics is the best. Couse it have many additional info like from where user came to you site etc.

Comment: I can't use Google Analytics. I need custom log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/cs-cz/services/application-insights/) for tracking user actitivy. You can track your own events, exceptions, etc. directly in JavaScript code.

```
appInsights.trackEvent("WinGame");

appInsights.trackEvent
  ("WinGame",
     // String properties:
     {Game: currentGame.name, Difficulty: currentGame.difficulty},
     // Numeric metrics:
     {Score: currentGame.score, Opponents: currentGame.opponentCount}
     );

appInsights.trackPageView
    ("page name", "http://fabrikam.com/pageurl.html",
      // String properties:
     {Game: currentGame.name, Difficulty: currentGame.difficulty},
     // Numeric metrics:
     {Score: currentGame.score, Opponents: currentGame.opponentCount}
     );
```